# Time out while applying Lambda function with consume to Google api

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

I have some tweets in a DataFrame and I want to know the sentiment of all of them (2050 tweets approximately)

I used the google cloud natural language API with the analyzeSentiment method to do it, something like this:

```
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types

def language_analysis(tweet):
client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
document = types.Document(
content = tweet,
type = enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT    
)
sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document).document_sentiment

return sentiment
```

Then I return the sentiment score and sentiment magnitude into the DataFrame, like this:

```
data['sentiment_score'] = data['Tweet'].apply(lambda twt : language_analysis(twt).score)
data['sentiment_magnitude'] = data['Tweet'].apply(lambda twt : language_analysis(twt).magnitude)
```

This works but only if the Dataframe has a few tweets, for several tweets it throws the error "InvalidArgument: 400 The language ar is not supported for document_sentiment analysis."

I think this happens because it is not an efficient way to do it, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably, after a few entries, you're hitting some entry with characters it doesn't understand. Instead of a lambda, write a function doing a `try`-`except`, and print out the stuff on which it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Using ‘try-catch’ would be useful to catch any unsupported language or characters in the tweet. Arabic is not currently supported by the API. Also, there is a [text content limit](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/quotas#content) of 1MB and [usage quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/quotas#requests) of 1000 requests per 100 seconds or 800,000 requests per day. Exceeding the limit could lead to API errors. You can edit your quotas and request for quota increase from Quotas page on Google Cloud Platform Dashboard.